# AO node black artifacts

Tags: materials, shaders, geometry

There are black tris all over the mesh with the Ambuient Occlusion node connected. Changing distance or samples does not help.

The subsurface modifier reduces black tris a litte but they are still visible. Can this mesh be fixed somehow? There are no doubles and normals are recalculated.
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

With subsurf:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nate suggested that you change the **Auto Smooth** value but in your file, this value panel is greyed out. This is because you have **Custom Split Normals** on your mesh.

[image]

Hit the **Clear Custom Split Normals Data** button and then try reducing the **Auto Smooth Angle** to something like 12 to 15 and that hopefully will clear your AO artifacts problem.

[image]

Edited to propose a different "solution"

I have no idea why but when moving the mesh and its origin to the **World Origin** a lot of the problem disappears! Perhaps someone can explain why?
[image]

After separating (**P**) a small part of the original model (less taxing on my PC) and moving it along with its origin to the **World Origin** most of the shading (shadowing) issues just disappeared:
[image]

Next some Vertex Smoothing to smooth out some of the sharper edges:
[image]

And finally with the auto smooth option unchecked: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it kind of works. The problem is that the smooth shading of the mesh is now off basically.

Comment: So this is not a solution since flat shading is without this problem even with Custom Split Normals Data.

Comment: This is so weird. But it finally works! Moving the object closer to the World Origin and scaling it down solves everything, so it was not a problem with *Normals in the end. I would really like to know why is this happening though. Maybe a bug? Anyway, thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

This is a *Normals issue. Go to edit mode, select everything by pressing "A", and then select *mesh*. In the mesh menu, select *normals* then select *re-calculate outside*.
If this does not work, then go to the vertex group tab in the properties tab, and check the box that says Normals *auto smooth*. Then set this value to about 25 degrees. Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: Not a solution unfortunately. There is a newly attached .blend file.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around trying to figure this out, I realized it has to do with scale. Turns out my character was too big, as soon as I scaled it down the artifacts disappeared.

Comment: Yes, the scale and the world origin as I mentioned it in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be because there is a mesh in the hierarchy that closely resembles the one you're trying to bake a texture on. Simply disable the camera icon (disable in renders) on the duplicate model, and bake again.